# Trying to get css for rails app to do word wrapping inside float

Tags: html, css

I've got some text that is roughly 20 lines.  Most lines are short, but some are long.  The text is inside a column and the page has two columns.  The problem is that long lines are causing interacting badly with the float.  Instead of to columns, I get one column stacked on top of the other.

I googled around and I think I should be able to use word-wrap, but adding it to my css does nothing.  What am I missing?

Here's css.

```
.two{
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

If there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Edit:  Here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/QUppe/embedded/result/).

Comment: Can you give us a simple js fiddle? (I don't think rails has anything to do with it)

Comment: No problem.  Link is now in body of post.

Comment: The two tables are too wide to fit side by side in the containing section

Comment: But they wouldn't be too wide if I could get word wrapping to happen inside of column two, right?  Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Word wrap is about super long words that reach the length of the container. Look here for clarity : http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/ I dont think word wrap is affecting your problem

Comment: Right, so it's the sitemap info a the bottom of the linked page that's causing trouble.  Because it's longer than the width of the container it's in, I thought word-wrap would be a suitable tool.  But if I've got that wrong, then what else could be causing this problem?

Comment: Ah, I think I know your problem then, mind if I post it as an answer to whore rep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue that only appeared in Chrome.

I found this post, which gave me the solution: http://ryan.stawarz.com/tech-tidbits/chrome-table-cells-not-word-wrapping-correctly/

I added these line to my the appropriate section of my CSS file and all was fixed.

```
table-layout: fixed;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is set at 100% width, thats fine but you have a 2px border on it. This brings the elements total width over 100% and such it will create a scrollbar, change width to 98%/99% or the exact amount of pixels and it should work (or just remove the border)

Comment: I pared down the footer to 98%, but it only made the footer smaller.  I set it to 600px, too, and got the same results.  So why does this look like a footer problem and not an issue with the column.two css?

Comment: I can't really tell to be honest, what browser are you using? I don't see a vertical scroll bar on that fiddle (using chrome)

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  My problem isn't really about a vertical scroll bar.  It's that I'd like the float right and float left elements to be next one another, but when the div for the float right has a long line in it, Chrome pushes it down below the float right area.